# Increasing high powers for elements of vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I would like to find an expression in R for the following:

Given a vector of *n* elements, I would like to return a vector for which the first element is to the power 1, the second element is to the 2nd power, third element to the third, and return the values.

e.g.

```
increasePower(c(1,2,3,4))
```

resulting in

```
> [1] 1 4 27 256
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use R's vectorised operations:

```
> increasePower  <- function(v) { v ^ (1:length(v)) }
> increasePower(1:4)
[1]   1   4  27 256
```

Comment: Or even: `v ^ seq_along(v)`